# Pushing ReactJS project to Bitbucket repository

Tags: reactjs, git, repository, bitbucket, push

I made React project with "npx create-react-app MyProject" and when i try to push it to previosly cloned Bitbucket repository i receive the following message

Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be commited)
MyProject/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit-a")

Comment: Tried `git add` and/or `git commit -a` ?

Comment: yes, i tried all of that

Comment: What were the outcomes? Any changes? Error messages?

Comment: You have first run the command `git add .` (this will add all untracked and changed files) and after that you have to run `git commit -m "--your commit message--" ` . Then you can run push command to push it to the repository

Comment: well i copied the folder and then wrote git add *.* , git commit -m "blabla", git push. Then i got output sth like i cannot track whole folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MarkoIgic: try an analogy here: *I tried to drive my car, and I got something like a bad sound. It wasn't actually a bad sound, it was just something like it. What could the problem be?* There's just not enough information to guess.